# Angular Js menu tab order is not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to achieve tab order for main menu drop down which is, while user tabbing to the parent menu item sub menu should get visible with tab order.

I have tried to use Accessible-Mega-Menu but no luck. Is there anyway to implement this or examples.

Here the sample [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12636/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div accessible-mega-menu="{
            uuidPrefix: 'accessible-megamenu',
            menuClass: 'nav-menu',
            topNavItemClass: 'nav-item',
            panelClass: 'sub-nav',
            panelGroupClass: 'sub-menu',
            hoverClass: 'hover',
            focusClass: 'focus',
            openClass: 'open'
        }">

</div>
 <ul class="nav-menu">

 <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#">Item A</a>
 </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#">Item B</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
     <a href="#">Item AAA</a>
   </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Item BBB</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Provide your code in the question, not only a link to.

Comment: you have an extra closing **</div>** tag remove it

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span ng-click="showChilds(items[0])">{{items[0].name}}</span>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in items[0].subItems" ng-show="items[0].active">
          <span>---{{subItem.name}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span ng-click="showChilds(items[1])">{{items[1].name}}</span>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in items[1].subItems" ng-show="items[1].active">
          <span>---{{subItem.name}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/p4kdL69e/)**

Comment: Menu should be open through Keyboard Tab order but in the example it is working only on hover.